# What does the sign on Thor's door actually say?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, team-thor

In the mockumentary, "Team Thor", there is a scene where Thor translates a sign on his door as saying

> Keep out, Daryl

Is that what it actually says in any discernable language or is it just a bunch of random runes on a plaque?

Here is the sign:

[image]

Comment: The runes themselves don't all look familiar, so I *suspect* it's just random runes (some made up, some legitimate historical runes). Plus, that's way too long to just say "keep out, Daryl".

Comment: @kutulumike its length is what I found most curious. If it does represent letters of some kind then it's meaning would probably be much more interesting than 'keep out'.

Comment: It could be "Asgardian" (e.g. fictional) and mean something flowery.

Answer (score 8):

It's nonsensical. The top row is the same seven characters repeated, and the lower row is a different set of seven characters repeated. They look similar to Elder Futhark, but some of them don't match anything in that set of runes.
The top row is:
ALWA??
The lower row is:
????AW?
Not sure what the runes above the top row and below the bottom row are.